# Logging in to an ASP.Net Forms Authentication site from an external web page

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, web, razor

I am in a situation where we have two different web applications, one a C# web forms application and the other a VB.Net vbhtml application.

I am needing to create one page where a user can log in to either system. So there is an area to enter the user name and password in one part of the page for the C# application and one on another part of the page for the vbhtml application.

Logging in to the vbhtml system is working fine. When attempting to log in to the C# web forms application that uses Forms Authentication, the first attempt in a browser fails regardless of whether the correct user name and password are entered or not. The second attempt will work with the correct credentials. I put some logging code in and it appears that the first time the Login.aspx page is accessed from the vbhtml form, the user name and password are not transmitted. The username and password keys are both in the request, but the values are empty. When the control is passed back to the vbhtml page and you attempt to login again, the values appear.

I am not certain if the ASP.NET_SessionId cookie is missing when a new browser visits the page and that causes an issue or if something else is at issue.

Can anyone shed any light on what may be the issue here? I have tried adding configuration settings to the C# application to allow anonymous access to the Login.aspx page, but that does not seem to have helped at all.

Comment: It sounds like you're kind of going after token-based authentication. You could set up a third project that just acts as an token-based identity provider. That way both websites can have users log in using the same central authentication server and then redirect back (basically like SSO). A free and easy to set up solution is IdentityServer4. Is this something like what you're trying to do?

Comment: I am actually trying to do something much simpler. The two systems do not share authentication at all. I am just wanting to be able to use www.website.com/login.vbhtml to post a form to either www.website.com/loginverify.vbhtml or to admin.website.com/LoginPassThru.aspx. The actual login is not shared between the two systems, the "powers that be" just want all of the users to go to one landing page to log in rather than administrators remembering to go to admin.website.com or have to click a link on www.website.com to log in.

Comment: Ok, I may be making some vast assumptions here, so correct me if I'm getting something wrong. You have a login page on both systems where you can login to the current system, or, optionally login to the other system. It sounds like maybe a CORS issue? Have you looked into this already?

Comment: Because it sounds like the second domain is denying the first request because it's coming from a different domain. Then, because of the failure, it's providing you a local copy of its login form. You submit it on the local domain, and because it's not going across domains anymore, it accepts and logs you in.

Comment: I ended up hacking a way around the issue. I have changed the main page of www.website.com from login.vbhtml to redirect.vbhtml which then sends the user to admin.website.com/directback.aspx which then sends the browser to www.website.com/login.vbhtml and at that point logging in works correctly. So now, everyone is happy but me lol.